# The first three Borderlands games got a update on Steam today, July 22, 2022? What did it do?

Tags: borderlands-2, borderlands, borderlands-the-pre-sequel

The first three Borderlands games got a update on Steam today, July 22, 2022? What did it do?

There's no News on the Store pages to tell me what happened.

Seashell the Otter [says](https://steamcommunity.com/app/49520/discussions/0/3467226415490791217/#c3467226415490889167):

> By the looks of it, the only thing that's changed is that they've removed the ads for Wonderlands. There's apparently even a website listing "patch notes" that are completely false, too, which I find hilarious.

Although some people are reporting graphical issues and crashes, so was it *just* that?

And on August 5th 2022, another update occurred which [seems](https://steamcommunity.com/app/261640/discussions/0/3454842785099926806/#c3454842785099952957) to have restored the ads?

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, the only official source of info I can find on the updates is this [2022-07-22 tweet from the official Borderlands Twitter account](https://twitter.com/Borderlands/status/1550288571709505537):

> **@Borderlands:** Today we released updates for BL1, BL2, & TPS. These updates made changes to the in-game news. We are currently
> investigating issues that have appeared since the updates went out,
> including how some text is displaying and console players being stuck
> loading the game.

Various reports at Reddit /r/Borderlands: [[1]](https://www.reddit.com/r/Borderlands/comments/w4z3bm/gearbox_on_twitter_today_we_released_updates_for/) [[2]](https://www.reddit.com/r/Borderlands/comments/w5kglx/so_is_bl1_unbroken_yet/) say that the advertisements for Gearbox Software's recent game, *Tiny Tina's Wonderlands* were removed ("changes to the in-game news"), among bug reports about glitched text.

> Now the counters in missions show up with weird characters in between the numbers.

> [...] there's a cosmetic problem with the display of numbers in text fields (like when mission instructions say to "collect X/Y thingies", where "X/Y" should be, say, "13/20", the numbers end up with fraction symbols and such in them).